# Can we use an Ipad Pro to compile xamarin ios projects with Visual Studio on a windows machine?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

The xamarin documentation mention that we need an MacBook connected to the network to be able to compile a xamarin ios project on a windows machine.
However can we use an IPAD Pro for this also ? Otherwise I have to buy a MacBook just to connect to my network ?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Comment: At the end of the day, you need to connect to a machine with Xcode installed and SSH to compile your iOS app. I'm pretty sure that you can't install Xcode on iOS, so an iPad Pro is out. (Someday maybe). It doesn't have to be a MacBook, but it does have to be a Mac. Lots of people use Mac Mini (you can get them refurbished pretty cheap), or have a Mac Pro with VMs that multiple developers can use. You can even get a cloud hosted mac (such as macincloud.com).

Answer (score 2):

No.  You need a Mac running a current version of OS X to act as a build host.  An iPad Pro does not run OS X.

Answer (score 1):

As Dylan S mentioned, getting a cloud hosted mac (like macincloud.com) would be the best solution for you. From what i've seen they got pretty reasonable plans and their website seems pretty informative